# Output log for bash

Tags: bash, scripts, log, mv

So I am executing a move script for some files that is older than 1 month every week as follow:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Moving Recordings Older than 30 days!";

/bin/find /var/services/homes/recordings/recording_list/ -type f -mtime +30 \
          -exec mv '{}' /var/services/homes/recordings/Old/recording_list/ \;
```

I want the script to create a stamped log file and record how many files were found and moved, with a new log file every week, any idea?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

To get a log file, add the `-v` option to `mv` and collect the output:

```
find srcdir  -type f -mtime +30 -exec mv -v {} destdir \; >output.log
```

If you want the log file to contain the date and you have a recent version of bash (>=4.2-alpha), use:

```
find srcdir  -type f -mtime +30 -exec mv -v {} destdir \; >"$(printf 'file%(%F)T.log' -1)"
```

If you don't have a recent bash, use `date` instead.

#### Faster version

For greater speed, use `-exec ... +`:

```
find srcdir  -type f -mtime +30 -exec mv -vt destdir {} + >|"$(printf 'file%(%F)T.log' -1)"
```

Instead of invoking a new `mv` process for every file found, this moves many files with a single instance of `mv`.